# How to load an external html in Material Design Component

Tags: angular, html, templates, external

I want to make an user registration form, but I wanna divide it in 3 tabs, the first tab for the username,password,phone and profile photo, the second tab for the address, country and city and the third tab for other datas.
I am using an angular material design component like mat-tab-group and I want make an independent form for each tab, and tell to the mat-tab-group component that load an external html template,something like that:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="2000ms">
    <mat-tab label="First">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
          <div>
            load my first template here
          </div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        Load my second one
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        Load the thirth template
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

Does anybody knows how I con do this in ANgular 7?

Comment: could you please clarify the question? Your template looks like the perfectly working one, just put the forms as the content and it will be fine. on the other hand, I would suggest you using [material stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) for forms rather than tabs

Comment: The link you sent my is great but it does exactly what Im avoiding to do , it is painting a form:
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
that form I wanna do it in one folder and load the template.html inside the angular material directive, do you know what I mean?